# Xcodeから初めてBitbuketリポジトリにpushしたらエラー

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

macOS Sierra バージョン 10.12.6
Xcode Version 9.2(9C40b)
の環境です。初めてBitbucketで作成したrepositoryにXcodeからremote pushしたいと思っています。

Xcodeのsource control navigatorによりRemotes Repositoryを登録できました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Remotes RepositoryはBitbuket(Git)です。もちろんBitbuketの自分のアカウントでもRepositoryを作成しています。README.mdもBitbuketのサイトで作成しています。

その状態で、BitbuketリポジトリにPushした所、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のようにまずRomote repositoryからPullしなさいとメッセージが表示されました。
次にPullを行うと、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のようにエラーが発生します。

サイトを検索すると、
mergeのオプションに「--allow-unrelated-histories」を付けて無関係なヒストリを持つブランチをマージする必要があるようですが、Xcodeでは同様の処理を行う部分が見つかりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのように対処すればいいかご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Comment: Bitbucketは試したことがないのですが、「README.mdもBitbucketのサイトで作成」したのが原因だと思われます。(初回push前にREADME.mdがコミットされてしまっているので「無関係のリポジトリ」として扱われている。)Bitbucket側は他はまだ空でしょうから、そっちは一旦削除してREADME.mdも何もない空のリモートリポジトリを作り直すのが一番楽なんじゃないかと思います。(README.mdは後からXcode側で作成して、commit/pushすれば良いだけ。)GitHubならそれで大丈夫なんですが、ダメならターミナルからコマンドライン版のgitを叩かないといけないかもしれません。

Comment: 新しくRepositoryを作成してREADME.mdを作成しなく、Pushしたらできました。おっしゃる通りのようです。しかし、BitbucketはREADME.mdを作成するか、一度PUSHしなければBitbuketサイトの「概要」からhttpsパスがわからないので、少々不便ですね。もしかして他の場所で確認できる場所があるのでしょうか。